# Multisampled framebuffer in OpenGL under Windows

Tags: opengl

How do I set the number of samples in the *default* framebuffer, given by Windows?

I found [this](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Multisampling#Microsoft_Windows_.28using_wgl.29) page, but although I use glew, there is no available `wglChoosePixelFormatARB` function in my context. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With WGL, you can only set the pixel format for a window once when you create the context, and you can only call the `wglChoosePixelFormatARB()` function once the client driver is loaded, and the client driver is only loaded once you have an OpenGL context.  Yes, that's circular.  So, this means you have to do the following:

1. Create a window with an OpenGL context.
2. Get the function pointer for `wglChoosePixelFormatARB()`.
3. Destroy the window, and create a new window with the desired pixel format.

If you've got any sense in you, you'll use SDL or GLFW to do this for you, because it's just a bunch of plumbing you have to write, there's no value in learning how to do it, and you probably want to get some real work done.  SDL/GLFW/etc. is how 99% of the OpenGL game devs out there do it.

If you really want to do this yourself and get stuck, look at the SDL or GLFW source code to see how they do it.

- In SDL, the [`src/video/windows/SDL_windowsopengl.c`](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/e12c38730512/src/video/windows/SDL_windowsopengl.c) file has a function `WIN_GL_ChoosePixelFormatARB()` which does what you want.  Also note the function `WIN_GL_LoadLibrary()`.
- In GLFW, the [`src/win32_window.c`](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/src/win32_window.c) file has a function `_glfwPlatformCreateWindow()` which does what you want.

P.S. GLEW is a bit broken with core contexts and modern cards, so watch out.  There are other GL loaders out there.

Comment: Can you recommend better "gl functions loaders" than glew?

Comment: @Pilpel: Unfortunately, I've only ever used two: I used GLEW and I rolled my own (by parsing the OpenGL API spec).  The problem with GLEW is that it doesn't work with core contexts, which *should* be a simple fix but they just haven't done it.  See: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library

Comment: "If you've got any sense in you, you'll use SDL or GLFW to do this for you, because it's just a bunch of plumbing you have to write" - yet you wrote tons of opengl function pointers code by yourself!?

Comment: @Pilpel: Because GLEW was *broken*.  I didn't write a bunch of function pointer code, I just wrote a script which spat it out.  The OpenGL API is available in XML format.

Comment: @Pilpel: What I wrote was similar to this one: https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home , and I didn't know about it at the time.

Comment: Ah I see. Are all `wgl` functions considered "core contexts"? What makes something "core"? Isn't it an extension? I'm a bit confused. Also, you're saying that glew can't retrieve the function pointer of `wglChoosePixelFormatARB()` as it does with other functions because, for that particular function, an opengl window has to be created first?

Comment: @Pilpel: It's complicated.  OpenGL supports two types of contexts: "core" and "compatibility".  Core means just the good stuff you want to use for new applications, compatibility includes old junk for legacy code.  WGL is an extra interface, in addition to vanilla OpenGL, which gives you the functions you need on Windows (like GLX on X11, or CGL on OS X).  Some WGL functions can just be linked in with the OpenGL DLL, but `wglChoosePixelFormatARB()` is part of an extension to WGL (which is why it ends with `ARB`) and therefore you need to load the function pointer, once you have a context.